# Ionic 4 Columns with ion-virtual-scroll not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have the current code:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-virtual-scroll [items]="places" approxItemHeight="200px">
        <ion-col size="12" size-lg="6" *virtualItem="let place">
          <ion-card (click)='viewDetails(place.id)' no-padding no-margin>
```

I want it to display my cards in two columns when the screen size is large. But it uses only one column of width 6 (50% of the screen) as shown below. If I remove the `<ion-virtual-scroll>` element and do an `<ng-repeat>` on the column it works great and makes two columns. Beta 19 here.

(Of note Ionic adds wrapping automatically, I'm trying to figure out why it's putting each element on a new row)

[image]

Comment: are you got any write answer?

Comment: Nope, I gave up on it. I'd think you'd have to do a VirtualScroll and setup each row to contain two of your "things" within one ion-item with some manual logic

Comment: so can you update your answer

Answer (score 1):

It won't work with Virtual Scroll. Virtual Scroll was made to render just the items visible on screen, so, virtual items should have approximately the same height and if you do that, the algorithm to calculate the height of screen won't work for both platforms.

To do that you're proposing, you should create your own VirtualScroll component and do different things depending on the width of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

A trick for ion-virtual-scroll support dynamic multiple columns.
you can use places index with pipe to fetch data from source
[ion-virtual-scroll support multi column](https://info-golab.medium.com/ionic-virtual-scroll-with-dynamic-multi-columns-703c5dd0d0e7)